# Right button drag with synaptics

Tags: xorg, synaptic, drag-and-drop

I thought it would be useful to tap-and-drag with two fingers, which would represent dragging with right mouse button. But after reviewing synaptic man options I can't see any option close to this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it today by accident! Configure two-finger tap as right button click. Then tap with two fingers, but drag with single finger.